# Where can I find a list of payment types, expense types etc. to use in a finance based software?

Tags: .net, finance

I am about to start a simple solo project at home. Basically to follow some expenses, payments etc.

Do you know any resource that lists the basic expense types, payment types, currency types and so which can be used by a finance related software so that I do not need to re-invent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean a list of currencies rather than currency types (which I don't know what it means), that's standardized in ISO 4217. See this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) for a list, including how many decimal points to use for each currency.

When it comes to payment types, I'd say that this is very dependent on the location. In the UK there's CHAPS and BACS for example, which I think are UK specific. I'd expect that expense types might also be location specific.

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for webservices that you can query (which would be my preferred option), then take a look at:

http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices

http://www.jambool.com/socialgold/developer/documentation/currency_api

or straight xml (including day rate):

http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

if you need to add currency conversion via javascript then maybe:

http://bidofury.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/javascript-currency-converter-with-json/

these are mostly currency related, but depending on your 'expense types' and 'payment types', there could well be api's out there per region that you could use as well.

i've used similar api's on many of my apps with great success.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at existing software for ideas, an open source finance system should have a database of lists etc?